# jquery transparent background in the drop down in the autocomplete menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this code however the drop down menu is not transparent and it looks messy

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js">
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>

<form action = "https://www.coinoracle.net/results" method = "POST">
<input type="text" name="the_coins" id="tags">
<input type="submit" value="Coin Divination">


</form>


    <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {% for my_coins in my_coins %}
            "{{my_coins}}",
        {% endfor %}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags

    });
  } );
  </script>
```

It works well but the background of the drop down menu is now transparent and it overlaps the other text in[image] the page, is there a simple way to make it solid white so it stays readable? Possibly without adding a css file or other manipulations, can I do it in the code on the html page?
unfortunately I don't know much about javascript...

Answer (score 1):

the answer is just add this in the html, it goes into the  inside the 
Like that you can make the background of the autocomplete of any colour you want

```
<style>


     .ui-autocomplete.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content{background-color: yellow;}


</style>
```

I hope this helps someone like me